# Which values are GetValueIn() and GetValueOut() calculate?

Tags: transactions, utxo, transaction-input

In Transaction.cpp, there is a function CAmount CTransaction::GetValueOut() const. 
In Coins.cpp, there is a function CAmount CCoinsViewCache::GetValueIn(const CTransaction& tx) const. 
My understand the GetValueIn() is calculater all vin value for a Tx.
But what the GetValueOut() calculate - all vout for a Tx?

Answer (score 1):

> But what the GetValueOut() calculate - all vout for a Tx?

Yes, it calculates the total value of all the outputs in the transaction. It also makes sure that the value is not out of range of the total supply of Bitcoin (21M).

Comment: JBaczuk, thank you so much for all your help.